# Does tsvector works with citext

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I have a `citext` column named `email` and also a `tsvector` column named `search` to do full text search. My trigger is like this:

`tsvector_update_trigger(search_vector, 'pg_catalog.english', name, email)`

`name` is just a normal `text` column. However, because `email` is `citext` which is text, but just case-insensitive, it appear that the trigger will not work. I have error that mention `email` is not of "character type". I am wondering why Postgres has difficulty treating citext as just text or cast to text and go about its business of tokenizing it?

How to have `email` remain as `citext` and still full-text searchable?

Answer (score 0):

why not just typecast the field to text and life is good? name::text should do. tsvector is case insensitive anyway.